# Cannot add mscorlib.dll to Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, mscorlib

Getting an error in C# Visual Studio.

I'm targeting .NET 4.7.2

When I try to add mscorlib I get this error message

A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is automatically referenced by the project system and cannot be referenced directly.

But when I build the file some references fail, like __DynamicallyInvokable.

Comment: You cannot add a reference to `mscorlib`, as the error says. Do you have a dll or project reference which in turn references a lower version of the framework?

Comment: I know what VS says, but then if it is already referenced in the target .NET then why am I getting errors referencing __DynamicallyInvokable? And no, there aren't any references to a lower version.

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete the bin and obj folder in your project-folder. Inside VS make a rebuild (ctrl+shift+b) and see if the error is gone.

Comment: This worked for me - had this error in my project files after using update-assistant to move to .NET 6.